# Change text color for exceptions in LogCat

Tags: android, eclipse

Folks, please advice where can I change text color for the output in LogCat using Eclipse. Text color for exceptions is that I can't see it.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you need to customize GTK settings (in case you use Linux) as described in [another post](http://askubuntu.com/a/131348/18533). In the meantime - [checkout this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7022857/356895).

Answer (score 8):

You will have to do it your self. In the meanwhile, you can use [this script](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/). The logcat output will look like this:

[image]

You can try to modify that script to make it show the Exceptions in the color you want.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't completely clear - I meant this all using Eclipse.

Comment: Give it a try though :) Every time I try to use the Eclipse's logcat I end up saying: *"gosh, this sucks... where's my command line, dude?"*

Comment: Wow... how did you realize it?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who just wants to change the text color within Eclipse, go to

`Window -> Preferences -> Android -> LogCat -> Colors`

There you can change the text colors for the different message types, but you can't change the background color, to do that you have to play around with a mix of Eclipse themes and Windows themes.

See Also:[This other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022820/change-android-logcat-font-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Cristian's answer (to use the script) may well be the best one but if you have the ability to debug in real-time on a physical device, try using the DDMS tool in the Android 'tools' folder. It gives very readable output.

Comment: Not if you have a dark background.