# Change Android LogCat font in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I can't seem to find the preference for changing the Android's LogCat debug output font in Eclipse. Can it be changed at all? How? I don't mind editing some preference file somewhere by hand, as long as it works.

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Found it. It's not grouped together with the other Eclipse font settings. It's in the Android > LogCat panel.

[image: So much for consistency]

Comment: How can we change the different colors of ERROR/INFO/DEBUG etc?

Comment: @Scott Biggs still works for me. Very good feature to use it with full-hd 13inch zenbook

Comment: @Pleerock: You're right! What was I thinking? It's right there, just like the picture. I feel like such a mouth breather. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To find anything in eclipse I always just open Eclipse > Preferences > and type in the filter text box.

In this case if you had typed 'LogCat' you would have found it :-D

Another good example is typing 'line numbers'

Comment: Yep, that is indeed how I found it. Sad but true, using full-text search to navigate a Preferences dialog.

Comment: Don't know which version you are using, but on 3.8.1, searching for LogCat produced nothing.

Answer (score 3):

In Preferences, search for 'Colors' not 'LogCat'. Then look for Android->LogCat->Colors. For some weird reason, eclipse does not show the color options if you search for LogCat.

Comment: What about the background color of the Logcat?