# Can I use special colors with logcat

Tags: android, logcat

I want to write some information to logcat but I want to specify the color of these texts , is it possible to do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Android LogCat font in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022820/change-android-logcat-font-in-eclipse)

Comment: That just changes the font.  He wants to output a logcat entry in a custom color.

Comment: http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/

Comment: The logcat is simply text. It does not have any sort of formatting beyond spaces, tabs, etc. Any color you see comes in your viewer of choice comes from that program reading and parsing the log.

Comment: my question is different from Change Android LogCat font in Eclipse , I want to customize the colors from D.log command not from IDE

Answer (score 1):

Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Logcat -> Colors

You can change some specific Logcat Message Colors from here (like Debug, Error messages).

If you want to use a Windows script, you can also check this link:

http://adrianvintu.com/blogengine/post/Colored-Logcat-Script-for-Windows.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your using Android Studio, you can change the colours, by clicking, Settings - Editor - Colours & Font - Android Logcat. You can then choose custom colours, for the Logcat level (Error, warning ...)