# How to display Unicode characters (Bengali fonts) in Logcat?

Tags: android, unicode, fonts, logcat

I am currently working on an application that fetches questions stored in the database of the server. However these questions are in the `Bengali` language. For debugging purposes I am logging the response from the server with `Log.d()`. As I see the Logcat is not able to  display these characters in Bengali fonts and it displays strings like `\u0986\u09ac\u09b9\u09be\u0993\u09af\u09bc\u09be`. Is there a way in which I can load a font to the Logcat so that it can display Bengali fonts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Bengali font into your system and then go to
 `Settings/Editor/Colors&Fonts/Console Font` and choose your Bengali font.

Comment: I guess this may work for the command line Logcat. Is there a way in which I can do this for the GUI Logcat in Eclipse?

Comment: `I guess this may work for the command line Logcat.` - unfortunately, yes. But thought many jumps with setup fonts. For Eclipse you can try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022820/change-android-logcat-font-in-eclipse